# Really simple linear animation formula

Tags: animation, language-agnostic

I can't quite seem to get my head around linear animation, as basic as it probably is. I'm just trying to animate a position from a start position to an end position over a given duration. Googling hasn't helped me here and my algebra skills have abandoned me. How do I do this? I've tried a number of different things but I just can't seem to get it right. Do I need linear interpolation?

Answers can be language agnostic (psuedocode, in your favorite language, whatever really), although I'm working in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need linear interpolation?

Yes.

You have distance (d) and duration(t). You also need to decide on a number of frames per second (f). After that it's just moving d / (t * f) each time.

Comment: Aha, okay. See, I knew it was going to be that simple. I just knew it. :p